# Excel VBA - Cannot Close New Workbook created using Workbook.Add

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that creates a new workbook and populates it with some data.

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.Range("A1") = "Dummy Text" 'Some code that populates data
wb.Activate 'wb.Activate or ThisWorkbook.Activate has no effect
```

The new workbook opens fine. I am able to minimise it, use the menus, etc. but am unable to click the close button.

If I go back to the original workbook that has the macro and come back to the new workbook, I can close.

How do I overcome this problem? Out of ideas unfortunately.

**My desidred use case**

Step 1 : User clicks a button -> A new workbook opens up with data

Step 2 : User reads the information in the new workbook and decides to save / close

But the close button in the new workbook won't work until the user goes back to the original workbook and comes again to the new workbook.

Comment: That can't be the actual code as it won't work. Anyway, you should not declare `As New Workbook` but just `As Workbook`.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Typo.

Comment: That still can't be the real code. Once fixed, I have no problem closing the new workbook. Which version of Excel are you using and where are you running the code from?

Answer (score 1):

after your code

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.Range("A1") = "Dummy Text"
```

insert

```
set wb = nothing
```

this will release your new workbook and you can close using the "X" in the top right.

P.S.: Sorry my english

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this line:

```
Workbooks("source").Close
```

if you want to close the current workbook , try this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveCell.Value = "CLOSE" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This would close the source workbook. My use case is that I want the user to read the infromation on the new workbook and then decide to close it or save it. But the close button on the top right won't work until I go back to the original workbook and then come back to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Dummy Text" 'Some code that populates data
wb.Activate 'wb.Activate or ThisWorkbook.Activate has no effect
End Sub
```

That worked fine on my excel. I click the close button and it has asked me if i want to save or not.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying your userform, make sure you use ".Show 0".